# Passing Arguments between script files

Tags: powershell, argument-passing

I need to pass a few arguments from one script in file to another one. I load path to my current script file to variable and add name, arguments of other script that I want to call.

Here is the sample of calling and passing argument that I got in `Script1.ps1`:

```
Param([string]$argument)
$thisScript = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
.($thisScript+'\anotherScript.ps1 -passedArgument '+$argument)
```

Here is the part of the script `Script2.ps1` that I'm calling:

```
Param([string]$passedArgument)
$passedArgument = "do some work with it HERE"
```

When I start the first script like this

```
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Script1.ps1 -argument datatopass
```

it writes the error

> The term 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Script2.ps1 -passedArgument datatopass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

When I try use the script manually like this

```
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Script2.ps1 -passedArgument datatopass
```

it works fine and doesn't report any error with wrong path or name.

I don't know where the problem is, and I couldn't find anything about this error.

Comment: did you noticed you missing the $ sign in: Param([string]passedArgument) ?

Comment: Yeah didnt noticed that i edited it. In my code its ok just forgot to add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to concat the passedArgument with its value to a string. Try:

```powershell
& (Join-Path $thisScript 'anotherScript.ps1') -passedArgument $argument
```

Comment: Yeah if i use ".(Join-Path $thisScript 'anotherScript.ps1') -passedArgument $argument" it works. Thank you